# Merge intersecting many-to-many relationships in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Given an `RDD[(A, B)]`, where there is a many-to-many relationship between `A` and `B`, how can I group the intersections of the relationships?

i.e. if a relationship can be drawn from one `A` to another `A` via one or more `B`s, then they should be grouped. Similarly, `B`s can group via `A`s.

For example, the collection:

```
(1, 'a')
(2, 'a')
(2, 'b')
(1, 'c')
(3, 'f')
(4, 'f')
(5, 'g')
```

should group into

```
([1,2], ['a','b','c'])
([3,4], ['f'])
([5], ['g'])
```

I can use `groupByKey` to obtain

```
(1, ['a', 'c'])
(2, ['a', 'b'])
(3, ['f'])
(4, ['f'])
(5, ['g'])
```

and also

```
('a', [1, 2])
('b', [2])
('c', [1])
('f', [3,4])
('g', [5])
```

But I'm not sure where to take it from here.

Comment: RDD do not support operations like this out of box!!! I think, the first step is correct. After any of the groupBy, you need to do a fold to a list as you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
object ManyToMany extends App {
  val m = List((1, 'a'),
    (2, 'a'),
    (2, 'b'),
    (1, 'c'),
    (3, 'f'),
    (4, 'f'),
    (5, 'g'))

  val mInt: Map[Int, Set[Char]] = m.groupBy(_._1).map { case (a, b) => a -> b.map { case (c, d) => d }.toSet }
  val mChar: Map[Char, Set[Int]] = m.groupBy(_._2).map { case (a, b) => a -> b.map { case (c, d) => c }.toSet }
  def isIntersect[A](as: List[Set[A]], bs: Set[A]): List[Set[A]] = as.filter { x => x.exists { y => bs.contains(y) } }
  val c = m.map { case (a, b) => mInt(a) }.foldLeft(List.empty[Set[Char]]) {
    case (sum, item) =>
      isIntersect(sum, item) match {
        case Nil => item :: sum
        case List(x) =>
          sum.filterNot(_ == x) ++ List(x ++ item)
      }
  }
  val d = c.map(x => (x, x.map(mChar(_)).foldLeft(Set.empty[Int]) {     case (sum, i) => sum ++ i }))
  println(d)
}
result:
List((Set(g),Set(5)), (Set(a, c, b),Set(1, 2)), (Set(f),Set(3, 4)))
```